# Should an independent mobile game developer incorporate a business?

Tags: canada, small-business, legal, incorporating

The story is thus: I am on the verge of publishing my first app, but I was thinking whether I should incorporate or not. I am an accounting student, albeit in second year with a budget of $1000. I am serious about the gaming industry and willing to go all in.

But would it be wise to start a company?

I am mostly concerned with taxes and keeping it separately from myself as I have greater plans in my mind.

EDIT:

I was able to determine the costs of incorporating, the paperwork required and how to file corporate taxes. I have definitely confirmed that the corporation will save a lot more taxes than being self-employed in the expected revenue brackets.

Comment: I'd say ask an accountant, but now I'm wondering what they teach you.  Is this possibly homework?

Comment: Nope no homework, accountant is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to asking an accountant, I would also ask a lawyer.  When exploring the same question for myself, I found that one of the benefits of incorporating or forming an LLC is that your personal assets are better protected.

Including asset protection, here are [5 reasons to incorporate](http://smallbusiness.foxbusiness.com/starting-a-business/2013/01/31/five-reasons-why-small-business-should-incorporate/):

> 1. Personal asset protection
> 2. Additional credibility and name protection
> 3. Perpetual existence
> 4. Tax flexibility
> 5. Deductible expenses

Initially, I thought that as I had so few assets, I should not be concerned.  I was glad I was able to do a free consult with a lawyer who advised me to look into forming an LLC.  (Ultimately, my planned business idea never panned out.  So, I never went the incorporation/LLC route.)  Hope this helps!